# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac3{2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How could we test the convergence of the following series?$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac3{2}}}.$$

The root test clearly fails and hence the ratio test. With what should I compare the series to? Is Dirichlet's or, Abel's test helpful? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Expontential is hiding ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac3{2}}}=\frac{(1+1/n)^n}{n^{3/2}}< \frac{e}{n^{3/2}}$$
Recall that $\sum_n 1/n^a$ is convergent iff $a>1$.

Comment: I noticed the resemblance to $e$. But, the fact is that the sequence $(1+\frac1{n})^n$ is inside the series symbol, which confuses me. Could you be more rigorous?

Comment: ok, understood. The series is bounded above, so trivial!

Comment: Note that $(1+\frac1{n})^n$ is an increasing sequence which tends to $e$.

Comment: Apart from this, does dirichlet, kummer or abel tests work?

Comment: @vidyarthi Abel test works

Comment: could you elaborate on abel test?

Comment: Take $a_n=1/n^{3/2}$ and $b_n=(1+1/n)^n$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test